# How to get a field's type by using CDT parser

Tags: parsing, eclipse-cdt, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to extract c++ source code's info.
One is field's type.

when source code like under I want to extract info's Type when info.call() is called.

```
Info info;
//skip
info.call(); //<- from here
```

Trough making a visitor which visit IASTName node, I tried to extract type info like under.

```
public class CDTVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

    public CDTVisitor(boolean visitNodes) {
        super(true);
    }

    public int visit(IASTName node){
        if(node.resolveBinding().getName().toString().equals("info"))
            System.out.println(((IField)node.getBinding()).getType()); 
            // this not work properly. 
            //result is "org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.ProblemType@86be70a"

        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self response.
The reason I couldn't get a binding object was the type of AST.

When try to parse C++ source code, I should have used ICPPASTTranslationUnit.
There is no code related this, I used IASTTranslationUnit as a return type of AST.

After using ICPPASTTranslationUnit instead of IASTTranslationUnit, I solved this problem.

Comment: Cool! How you used the ICPPASTTranslationUnit? I am workin in a standalone C++ parsing using the Eclipse CDT and I also need to solve the binding. I wrote some code, but the AST is not working properly. If you could share your code I will be thankfull.

Comment: @FelipeGomes to resolve binding you need to use indexer but the indexer has coupling with eclipse studio.

Comment: @FelipeGomes Have a look at [this](https://github.com/juga999/cpp-sensor-core).. It does indexing as StandAlone

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code is in fact valid, a variable's type resolving to a `ProblemType` is an indication of a configuration problem in whatever tool or plugin is running this code, or in the project/workspace containing the code on which it is run.

In this case, the type of the variable `info` is `Info`, which is presumably a class or structure type, or a typedef. To resolve it correctly, CDT needs to be able to see the declaration of this type.

If this type is not declared in the same file that's being analyzed, but rather in a header file included by that file, CDT needs to use the project's **index** to find the declaration. That means:

- The AST must be index-based. For example, if using `ITranslationUnit.getAST` to create the AST, the overload that takes an `IIndex` parameter must be used, and a non-null argument must be provided for it.
- Since an `IIndex` is associated with a CDT project, the code being analyzed needs to be part of a CDT project, and the project needs to be indexed.
- In order for the indexer to resolve `#include` directives correctly, the project's include paths need to be configured correctly, so that the indexer can actually find the right header files to parse.

Any one of these not being the case can lead to a type resolving to a `ProblemType`.

Comment: Yes! I just put nul value to Index. I think that's the point.
Is there any DOCs. or examples to see how to use index?

Comment: @Ui-GyunJeong: Maybe https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c7/CDT_APIs_for_code_introspection.pdf is helpful? The general idea is that the code needs to be in a project, and you get the index from the project.

Comment: @Ui-GyunJeong: This might also be useful background info: https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/Overview_of_Parsing

Comment: Wow!! really nice info!!  What I really want is that. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to use cdt parser out of eclipse. To use index, I have to make project object. I think project means Eclipse project. Do you know how to make or handle project object out of eclipse?

Comment: @Ui-GyunJeong: Are you writing an Eclipse plugin?

Comment: No i dont. I am trying to develop c++ source code analyzer which is not eclipse plug in.

Comment: @Ui-GyunJeong: See my comment on your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I figure it out! Here is the entire code which can index all files in "src" folder of a cpp project and output the resolved type binding for all code expressions including the return value of low level API such as memcpy. Note that the **project** variable in following code is created by programatically importing an existing manually configured cpp project. I often manually create an empty cpp project and programatically import it as a general project (once imported, Eclipse will automatically detect the project type and complete the relevant configuration of CPP project). This is much more convenient than creating and configuring a cpp project from scratch programmatically. When importing project, you'd better not to copy the project or containment structures into workspace, because this may lead to infinitely copying same project in subfolder (infinite folder depth). The code works in Eclipse-2021-12 version. I download Eclipse-For-cpp and install plugin-development and jdt plugins. Then I create an Eclipse plugin project and extend the "org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications" extension point.
In another word, it is an Eclipse-Application plugin project which can use nearly all features of Eclipse but do not start the graphical interface (UI) of Eclipse. You should add all cdt related non-ui plugins as the dependencies because new version of Eclipse does not automatically add missing plugins any more.

```
        ICProject cproject = CoreModel.getDefault().getCModel().getCProject(project.getName());
        // this code creates index for entire project. 
        IIndex index = CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().getIndex(cproject);
        
        IFolder folder = project.getFolder("src");
        IResource[] rcs = folder.members();
        // iterate all source files in src folder and visit all expressions to print the resolved type binding. 
        for (IResource rc : rcs) {
            if (rc instanceof IFile) {
                IFile f = (IFile) rc;
                ITranslationUnit tu= (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(f);
                index.acquireReadLock(); // we need a read-lock on the index
                ICPPASTTranslationUnit ast = null;
                try {
                    ast = (ICPPASTTranslationUnit) tu.getAST(index, ITranslationUnit.AST_SKIP_INDEXED_HEADERS);
                } finally {
                    index.releaseReadLock();
                }
                if (ast != null) {
                    ast.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
                        @Override
                        public int visit(IASTExpression expression) {
                            // get the resolved type binding of expression. 
                            IType etp = expression.getExpressionType();
                            System.out.println("IASTExpression type:" + etp + "#expr_str:" + expression.toString());
                            return super.visit(expression);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```